# error in creating horizontal list view

Tags: android, listview

I am working on one [example](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) on horizontal list view . Just modified the package name as `package com.example.horizaontal;` and modified the layout `listviewdemo`

```
<com.example.horizaontal.HorizontialListView
      android:id="@+id/listview" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:background="#ddd"/>
```

But it threw error for inflating class for liner layout, the above code is in `LinerLayout`.
Please help me

Comment: may be package name is not absolutely same...post logcat ..that'll be more helpful ...

Comment: HorizontialListView is declered in the same package com.example.horizaontal

Comment: try to clear your project and rebuild.

Comment: @pitambar ... put logcat

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifestfile,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your modified package"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="your packagename .your class name"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
         </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

After correcting this mistake clean your project.

Project -> clean

Hope It helps you

Comment: android:name="com.example.horizontal.HorizontalListViewDemo" in manifest file it give clss not found exception

Comment: paste your HorizontalListView class

Comment: check your HorizontalListView class it must extends the View class

Comment: HorizontalListView class is extending AdapterView<ListAdapter>

Answer (score 0):

Check your xml files. There you will find your customized HorizontialListView's fully qualified class name(something like com.youroldpackagename.HorizontialListView) as old one. Replace it with new package name.

Comment: you will have to update that fully qualified class name according to your new package name.